# Merge grid and point vectors in Qgis

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, vector-grid

In qgis
I have a grid,
 i have a point vector
 for each cell of the grid, i want to make the mean of one attribute of the vector.
How can I do that by not making a raster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS 2.18.20 you can use the tool "Join attributes by location" in the Vector menu.

With this tool, you have the possibility to resume attribut (sum, mean, min, max or median)